Understanding meaning of a sentence
I am writing a quiz question and want to add two conditions. Consider thesetwo sentences:
The word cannot contain the character 'e' for a maximum of four times.
The word must contain the character 'e' for a maximum of four times.
By the second sentence, I meant: The character 'e' can appear up to 4 times in the word. This means the word can have 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 occurrences of the letter 'e'. I just negated the sentence and made the first. But do not know what it means.
What's the meaning of the first? I know the second one sets a limit of maximum appearance of character 'e' four times in the word. But what does the first line mean?
Is the meaning of the first the same as:
The word must contain the character 'e' for a minimum of four times.
Or there remains a difference.

Welcome! What is the source of the two sentences? Neither is very natural English.

for a maximum of x times in your sample is pretty weird.

If you found these sentences somewhere, please give more context that might help us guess the meaning. If you made them up, please tell more about the meaning you want. "Contain ... for" is not idiomatic, and regardless of idiom, the first sentence combines contradictory ideas so hard that it's impossible to guess at a meaning. Your proposed meaning, a minimum of 4, is certainly not communicated clearly by it. Voting to close for now as unclear.

The two conditions seem contradictory. Instead of trying to figure out the meaning of sentences you invented, it would be better to be clear what the quiz question is. Most English words contain 0 to 4 of letter e, but proof-reading is off topic anyway.

I've voted to migrate to ELL, but the question doesn't make much sense anyway, because it seems to be presenting a non-idiomatic utterance with uncertain meaning, and asking how to negate that more-or-less invalid utterance.

Aside: the max occurrence of letter e that I can find is 5, such as beekeeper, effervescence etc.


The sentence "The word must contain the character 'e' for a maximum of four times" is not perfectly clear. The words you used when explaining your meaning, "the word can have ___ occurrences of the letter 'e'," are clearer. (You might replace "0, 1, 2, 3, or 4" with "up to 4," or for maximum clarity, "between 0 and 4." Or reword, like "must have no more than 4 occurrences.) The "must" seems to suggest that at least some "e"s must be present, while "can" makes it clearer that zero "e"s is an option.
The problems with the first sentence are not just grammatical. It's that some ideas can't be easily inverted. What's the "opposite" of "between 0 and 4 occurrences"? You can't count how many times the letter "e" doesn't show up. The problem is not just that the sentence is unclear, it's that we don't know what we want it to mean. So the direct answer to your main question is: just negating the second sentence doesn't create a new sentence with a clear meaning.


Thanks for the answer. So, would you kindly propose me a way to create a sentence negating the opposite meaning to the second sentence?

@M.Riyan Well, that's what I mean; there's no opposite of the idea of "doesn't have to contain 'e', but if it doesn, must not have more than four." Do you want the opposite to be "must contain more than four"? Or maybe "must not contain any"?

Alright. I understood it. Thanks..

@M.Riyan For those I might say simply "The word must not contain more than four occurrences of the letter 'e'," or "The word must not contain the letter 'e.'"

OP has enquired

Is the meaning of the first the same as:
The word must contain the character 'e' for a minimum of four times.

Here are other alternative way of framing the question:

The word cannot contain more than four instances of the letter 'e'." (More than 4 e's are not allowed.)
The word may contain up to four instances of the letter 'e'." (maximum 4 e's are allowed)
The word must not exceed four 'e's."
The word can have a maximum of four 'e's."

Youu can use these alternatives:

"e" occurs:

Exactly four times
At least four times
No more than four times
Up to four times
Four or fewer times



